# How to decode url in Grafana?

Tags: grafana, urldecode

There are some variables in my data sources that have been encoded to url in the format like this :

%E5%AE%A1%E6%A0%B8%E5%8F%B0%E7%9A%84%E6%8E%A5%E5%8F%A3%E7%9B%AE%E5%89%8D%E8%B0%83%E7%94%A8%E4%BC%9A%E6%9C%89%E9%97%AE%E9%A2%98%E5%90%97%EF%BC%8C%E5%AE%A1%E6%A0%B8%E5%8F%B0%E7%9A%84%E6%A8%A1%E5%9D%97%E5%86%85%E5%AE%B9%E4%BC%9A%E6%AF%94%E6%9F%94%E6%80%A7%E5%B0%91%EF%BC%8C%E6%88%91%E6%95%B4%E7%90%86%E4%B8%80%E4%B8%8B%E5%AE%A1%E6%A0%B8%E5%8F%B0%E6%B6%89%E5%8F%8A%E7%9A%84%E6%A8%A1%E5%9D%97%EF%BC%9F

How to decode it in Grafana so that I can see the understandable content ?

googled the question didnt find any answer about it.

Comment: My browser's URL bar translated it to Chinese text. If I understand the question, you want to decode and display that text in Grafana...

Comment: yes, thats what i want